# PHPMyAdmin and Security on XAMPP not working after changing DocumentRoot in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, xampp, httpd.conf

**SUMMARY**

I am unable to run localhost/phpadmin and localhost/security after changing the DirectoryRoot in XAMPP httpd.conf.  This leads to two questions.

1. If I am using XAMPP on Windows, is there any way to run PHP files outside the localhost directory that I have set in the httpd.conf?
2. If "no", then how does one run files such as phpmyadmin or the security module on the local machine, if the phpmyadmin files reside in the c:\xampp directory but the DocumentRoot path in httpd.conf points to a different directory?

More detail is set out below.

**BACKGROUND INFO**

My installation is as follows.

- Operating system: Windows 7
- Version of XAMPP:  `xampp-portable-lite-win32-1.8.1-VC9.7z`
- Installation directory:   `c:\xampp-portable`
- Code files saved in: `d:\dropbox\websites_user1\...`

I then modified the httpd.conf as follows:

```
Line 191: DocumentRoot "D:/Dropbox/websites_user1"
Line 222: <Directory "D:/Dropbox/websites_user1">
```

The default httpd-xampp.conf configuration is unchanged - e.g.:

```
Line 99:  Alias /phpmyadmin "/xampp-portable/phpMyAdmin/"
Line 100: <Directory "/xampp-portable/phpMyAdmin">
Line 121: <LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
```

**THE PROBLEM**

After changing the directory root in httpd.conf as above, I can run php files successfully from local host - e.g. localhost/project01/demo.php.

However, I now can't run PHP files from any location other than those located in the new localhost directory (i.e. d:/Dropbox/websites_user1/..).  This means that I can no longer run PHP files in locations such c:\xampp\PHPMyAdmin or C:\xampp-portable\security\htdocs\security.php.

Also, the configuration for the PHPMyAdmin and Security are clearly no longer correct.  For instance, if I enter "localhost/phpmyadmin" or "localhost/security", I get a "page not found" error.

This leads to two sets of questions (as summarised at the start of this question).

1. Is the directory configured as the localhost the ONLY location from which PHP files can be run?  Is it possible to configure PHP to run from any location on my C or D drives?
2. If not, how do I run files such as those in PHPMyAdmin or security.php or any of the innumerable files in the other xampp directories?  Do I need to copy and paste the phpmyadmin folder into my localhost folder at D:/Dropbox/websites_user1?  Or into each of the individual website folders beneath that?  If yes, do I then need to reconfigure any files such as http-xampp.conf?

I am relatively new to PHP and new to XAMPP.  Everything was working perfectly until I ran into this ... and now I'm completely stuck if I can't use PHPMyAdmin, and can't even use the Security module to set my passwords.

Will be very grateful for advice!!

Comment: Do visit this link, it solved my problem. Hope it solves yours.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970344/httpd-xampp-conf-how-to-allow-access-to-an-external-ip-besides-localhost

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cant run anything higher than your root as a security feature. Imagine some remote person knowing your IP address and accessing all your files above your document root.