# httpd-xampp.conf: How to allow access to an external IP besides localhost?

Tags: apache, xampp, httpd.conf

I haven't found the right answer that works for me in other questions.
This is how the `httpd-xampp.conf` looks like originally:

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

What should I do if I want to add another IP address besides the `Require local`?

For example, below `Require local` I have tried the following:

```
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

That is to say:

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        Require local
        allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

But it still blocks the access to that external IP.

How do I fix this?
How can I add more IP addresses to allow them access?

I am using XAMPP 5.6.3 under a Windows environment.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`allow from all` will not work along with `Require local`. Instead, try `Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xx`

For Example:

```
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Require local
    Require ip 10.0.0.1
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Hello ! i have installed xampp on windows server 2012. i have a public IP and entered like this "Require ip my-ip"
still i can't access my localhost from IP
Thanks

Answer (score 16):

I tried this and it works. Be careful though. This means that anyone in your LAN can access it. Deepak Naik's answer is safer.

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    # Require local
    Require all granted
ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This is what i added in the end of file \xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf file before  tag

Answer (score 4):

Add below code in to file d:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf:

```
<IfModule alias_module>
...
    Alias / "d:/xampp/my/folder/"
    <Directory "d:/xampp/my/folder">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Above config can access from http://127.0.0.1/

Note: someone suggest that replace from `Require local` to `Require all granted` but not work for me

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    # Require local
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
For Ubuntu xampp,
Go to /opt/lampp/etc/extra/
and open httpd-xampp.conf file and add below lines to get remote access,
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
    Allow from all

in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin section.
```

And restart lampp using,  `/opt/lampp/lampp restart`

Answer (score 0):

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
```

add to txt file > httpd-xampp.conf

Answer (score 0):

**If you want get access from specific IP from your pc or phone**

<Directory "c:/webserver/www/">
  #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
  Allow from ::1
  Allow from localhost
  Require local
  Require ip 192.168.5.6
</Directory>

**it  work 100% !!!**

Answer (score -1):

```
<Directory "E:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/">
AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
```

Answer (score -1):

In windows all you have to do is to go to windows search Allow an app through Windows Firewall.click on Allow another app select Apache and mark public and private both . Open cmd by pressing windows button+r write cmd than in cmd write ipconfig find out your ip . than open up your browser write down your ip http://172.16..x and you will be on the xampp startup page.if you want to access your local site simply put / infront of your ip e.g http://192.168.1.x/yousite. Now you are able to access your website in private network computers .

i hope this will resolve your problem

Answer (score -1):

allow from all will not work along with Require local. Instead, try Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xx

For Example:

```
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Require local
    Require ip 10.0.0.1
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score -3):

Open for new app "HTTPD" (Apache server) in your Firewall

Take a look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqgUGF3NnuM

Comment: can you share the main steps described in the youtube link here, so your answer is still helpful if the video is no longer available?