# Hosts - Access local website with external device

Tags: apache, xampp, vhosts, hosts

After hours of searching and googling I've still not found anything so I decided to ask here.

I've set up a virtual host called test.dev. This means that I can have access one of my local `XAMPP` projects by typing that to an address bar. The set up is following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test"
    ServerName test.dev
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/test">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
        Order allow,deny  
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It works perfectly fine on my local computer but if I want to access it using an external device connected to a same network, it doesn't.

The question is how should I set up my hosts - file in order to have access to that project with external devices?

I've tried with following:

```
 192.168.0.10    test.dev # Ip address
 127.0.0.1       test.dev # Local address
```

But it only works on my local computer. Is it even possible to target same server name twice on different IP's?

E: I figured it out! For all of those wondering the same as I was, here's the answer to get it work on all devices that are connected to a same network.

1. Install NPM
2. With NPM, install grunt
3. Install grunt-localtunnel-me
4. After installing, start it with command: `lt --port 80 --subdomain "name of the wanted subdomain"`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to verify following thing if its working or not.

1. Make sure that your port 80 is open for all. Check your windows firewall. If you want to allow everyone to access port 80 then follow instruction list [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7)
2. Allow xampp-apache is accessible from outside. you can follow instruction from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970344/httpd-xampp-conf-how-to-allow-access-to-an-external-ip-besides-localhost)

If you above steps fails then share some screen shot with error messages.