# Hosting php application on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, hosting, windows-server-2008

I have installed xampp on my local machine as well as Windows Server 2008 and Apache and MySql is running on both.
I created a test application which I am running on my local machine.

```
http://localhost/example/
```

I want to test this example application on the server. How can I do this?

adding `192.168.1.11/example/`(ip address of the server) gives me `404 - File or directory not found.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to move those files over to the server instance. and make a change in your XAMPP configuration to allow the IP of your local machine to connect to the instance.

Do you have physical access to the server instance? (I.E. VM/SSH, In basement)

This question might be helpful if you are looking to allow an external IP.
[httpd-xampp.conf: How to allow access to an external IP besides localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970344/httpd-xampp-conf-how-to-allow-access-to-an-external-ip-besides-localhost)

Comment: Hi, yes I have physical access to the server. Thanks

Comment: Then you would have to move the files over from one box to the other and then follow the steps in the link provided to allow your local machine to connect to it to view your files.